# Vertical align and centre multiple divs using Flexbox

Tags: reactjs, css, flexbox, material-ui

I am trying to vertically align two set of rows, each of which contains an image on one side, and text on the other side. Although I have experience with using flex to align vertically by using the code below, seems like in this particular situation I have to use something different:

```
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  text-align: center;
```

This is what I am trying to achieve (Note that the red box is the image while the gray box is the text):

[image]

However, I am getting the situation below, with the text not vertically centered but top aligned with the image:

[image]

This is how the DOM structure looks like (ReactJS):

```
<LandingPinkDiv>
  <Grid container spacing={24}>
    <Grid item xs={12}>
      <LandingTitleWhite>Title</LandingTitleWhite>
    </Grid>
    <LandingRowDiv>
      <Grid item xs={6}>
        <LandingImageDiv>
          <LandingImage
            src={1}
            width="320px"
            height="304px"
          />
        </LandingImageDiv>
      </Grid>
      <Grid item xs={6}>
        <LandingTextContainer>
          <LandingSubheadingWhite>
            Subheading
          </LandingSubheadingWhite>
          <LandingSubtitleBlack>
            SubTitle
          </LandingSubtitleBlack>
        </LandingTextContainer>
      </Grid>
    </LandingRowDiv>

    <LandingRowDiv>
      <Grid item xs={6}>
        <LandingTextContainer>
          <LandingSubheadingWhite>
            SubHeading
          </LandingSubheadingWhite>
          <LandingSubtitleBlack>
            Subtitle
          </LandingSubtitleBlack>
        </LandingTextContainer>
      </Grid>
      <Grid item xs={6}>
        <LandingImageDiv>
          <LandingImage
            src={2}
            width="320px"
            height="197px"
          />
        </LandingImageDiv>
      </Grid>
    </LandingRowDiv>
  </Grid>
</LandingPinkDiv>
```

The CSS counterpart is like this:

```
export const LandingRowDiv = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  /* justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  text-align: center; */
  margin-bottom: 10%;
  padding-left: 10%;
  padding-right: 10%;
`;

export const LandingPinkDiv = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  text-align: center;
  height: 170vh;
  background: #e72564 !important;
`;


export const LandingTextContainer = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  text-align: center;
  margin-right: 10%;
`;
```

Comment: Can you create a [mcve] with the rendered html and css please?

Comment: use `align-items: center`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `align-items: center` to your `LandingRowDiv` styled component:

```
export const LandingRowDiv = styled.div`
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: row;
  text-align: center
  margin-bottom: 10%;
  padding-left: 10%;
  padding-right: 10%;
`;
```

Comment: I will accept this as the correct answer, however I also had to use the `flex-direction: row` to keep the image and text in the same row

Answer (score 0):

You should use `align-items: center;` in 'LandingRowDiv' styled-component.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I get it right but you could consider the following html

```
<figure>
    <img src="" alt="">
    <figcaption>
        <p>Text</p>
    </figcaption>
</figure>
```

And then the following css

```
figure {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
}

figure img {
    width: 50%;
}

figure figcaption {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 50%;
}
```

(you can use align-self on p instead of align-items)